# time and space complexity of the following code:

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
val = [5,6,7,8]
possible_combinations = [[]]
while val:
    person = val.pop()
    new_combinations = []
    for team in possible_combinations:
        new_combination = [person] + team
        new_combinations.append(new_combination)
    possible_combinations += new_combinations
```

Is it O(2^(n-1)) or O(n*(2^(n-1)))?
I am confused between the above 2 complexity. Can anyone please give some input about the complexity?

Comment: What is your `n` here? the length of `val`? In this specific piece of code, because `n` is  known, it is `O(1)` both space and time...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its Program for Calculating permutation using Iterative method
Its time complexity will be **O(N∗2^N)**

Refer this code explanation for more details

https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-the-coding-interview/gx2OqlvEnWG